# unique factorization without fundamental theorem?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

For an arbitrary polynomial $P(x)$ over ${\bf C}$, can it be shown that IF $P(x)$ can be factored, THEN the factorization is unique, without using the fundamental theorem of algebra, and only elementary methods (for example, not analytic continuation)?

Answer (score 3):

Unique factorization does not need analysis or the fundamental theorem of algebra: when $K$ is any field at all (not just the complex numbers), $K[x]$ has unique factorization. This is proved in many abstract algebra textbooks.

A more technical result, also proved in many abstract algebra textbooks, is that if the integral domain $A$ has a unique factorization then $A[x]$ has unique factorization. But the proof when $A$ is a field is much simpler (because $K[x]$, as mentioned in a comment below, is in fact Euclidean when $K$ is a field, but it turns out that $A[x]$ is not Euclidean when $A$ is an integral domain that's not a field).

Comment: To add: it is proved in many texts that $K[x]$ is even a Euclidean domain, so it is a PID, and thus a UFD!

Comment: I appreciate the answers and their insights, but I am looking for an elementary argument, rather than as a corollary of a more general argument, for something I am writing for a more general audience.  Probably should have said that at the outset.

Comment: It would help if you explain what it is you're writing for the general audience and what background you want to assume they have: are they allowed to know $\mathbf Z$ has unique factorization?  The proofs that $\mathbf Z$ and $K[x]$ have unique factorization are nearly the same: see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/uniquefactnZF[T].pdf.